# AJAX call liferay portal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, liferay

I'm making a web site with liferay 5 portal. I have one portlet which contains a list (select html tag ..) of portlets. Each portlet is loaded or should be loaded with an AJAX call when the selected item in list change (change event jQuery ..).
Meanwhile when I do my AJAX request the response from server is a redirection and the div which should contains the portlet contains the whole web page.

```
Query.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : url,
data : {
    p_p_id : 'GlossaryManagement_WAR_chorusportlet',
    p_l_id : plid,
    p_p_state : 'exclusive',
    p_p_lifecycle : '1',
    p_p_mode : 'view',
            //index in list
    portlet : '1'
},
success : function(message) {
    console.log("succes");
    console.log(message)
    jQuery("#maincontent").append(message);
},
error : function(message) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(message);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Liferay 5, try using 'exclusive' windowState in your url as explained over [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/7200468).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the url ... this ajax call is good and works "perfectly" if this word has sense in programming .

Regards